# Saving password to local i/o security issue on python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write auto-login function on web crawing.

I think get id and password in incipient stage. Then I save the information, and

will use the saved data after next login.

I think ID is able to be saved purely. But Password might be secured.

I found method,

- make json file and put it on priviate region. And load it when need login

But the method wasn't involved encrypt password, so password was plain.

- save hashed password
  if the code is in git or copyed, it is not secured.

What method can be recommended?

Comment: Put the data into the / a keychain / keyring.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. I want to get the concept  like keyring. Thanks for your help.